# Why is the result of func(44,8) 54?

Tags: c

This is the code.

```c
const static char NUMBERS[16]
= {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ,'7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B','C','D','E','F'};

void func(long num, int num2)
{
    long temp = num;

    if (num <= 0)
        return;
    temp /= num2;

    func(temp, num2);
    printf("%c", NUMBERS[num % num2]);
}

int main(void)
{
    func(7, 2);
    puts("");
    func(44, 8);
    puts("");
    func(2023, 16);
}
```

Thinking about func(44,8)
I thought at void func
func(44,8) becomes func(5,8) and
it prints NUMBERS[44%8] == NUMBERS[4], which is 4.

and func(5,8) becomes func(0,8) and
it prints NUMBERS[5%8] == NUMBERS[5], which is 5.

So, I thought that result would be 45.
But the actual result was 54.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis is correct:

> Thinking about func(44,8) I thought at void func func(44,8) becomes func(5,8) and it prints NUMBERS[44%8] == NUMBERS[4], which is 4.
>
> and func(5,8) becomes func(0,8) and it prints NUMBERS[5%8] == NUMBERS[5], which is 5.

But note the last two lines in the function:

```c
func(temp, num2);
printf("%c", NUMBERS[num % num2]);
```

The function is first called recursively, and only then the result is printed.

Let's walk through it:

1. `func(44,8)` is called

   1. It calls `func(5,8)`

      1. It calls `func(0,8)`, that just returns
      2. The `func(5,8)` prints 5
   2. `func(44,8)` prints 4
2. The overall output is 5 and then 4, or "54".

Comment: I really appreciate your help :)
It was so helpful. Thank you